# Pretty URL's using Laravel's Route::resource RESTful methods

Tags: php, rest, url, laravel

I have just started learning Laravel and would like to know if it is possible to create a Route::resource that would allow me to access the below URL using RESTful methods:

I would like the URL to look like this:

```
http://example.com/articles/2014/09/22/this-is-the-article-title
```

And I would like to access this from my ArticlesController using:

```
//GET articles/{year}/{month}/{day}/{title}
public function show($year, $month, $day, $title) {
    $article = //find article in DB
    return View::make('articles.show')->with('article', $article);
}
```

From what I've gathered so far, this can somehow be accomplished by doing something like the below in the routes.php file:

```
Route::resource('year.month.day.articles', 'ArticlesController');
```

But that doesn't quite look right to me.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Resource controllers are useful for building RESTful controllers that form the backbone of APIs.  The general syntax is this:

```
Route::resource('resourceName', 'ControllerName');
```

This will create [seven different routes](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#restful-resource-controllers) in a single call, but is really just a convenience method for doing this:

```
Route::get('/resourceName',                 'ControllerName@index');
Route::get('/resourceName/{resource}',      'ControllerName@show');
Route::get('/resourceName/create',          'ControllerName@create');
Route::get('/resourceName/{resource}/edit', 'ControllerName@edit');
Route::post('/resourceName',                'ControllerName@store');
Route::put('/resourceName/{resource}',      'ControllerName@update');
Route::delete('/resourceName/{resource}',   'ControllerName@destroy');
```

The URLs are *only* based off of the resource's name that you specify, and the method names are built in. I am not aware of any way that you can modify those using resource controllers.

If you want pretty URLs, then assign those routes without using a resource controller:

```
Route::get('/articles/{year}/{month}/{day}/{title}', 'ArticlesController@show');
```

Note that if you do use the `show` method, this will conflict with any REST-ful URL that you may have defined previously (the `show` method in a resource controller will only expect 1 parameter passed in, namely the ID of the resource to show).  For this reason I would recommend you to change the name of that method to something else.

Comment: Thank for your response. I am new to RESTful development and your answered helped clarify my situation.